# vb.net Automatically creating closing tags

Tags: vb.net, tags, richtextbox

I wanted to create a WYSIWIG html edditor in vb.net and have a rich textbox control Im trying to auto create closing tags for every open tag created but dont know how to go about this?

for instance if the user types   the htmy edditor will auto place directly underneath it

```
        Dim startingPoint As Integer = -1
    Do
        startingPoint = RichTextBox1.Find("<Body>", startingPoint + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        If (startingPoint >= 0) Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = startingPoint
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = "<Body>".Length
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue

            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "</Body>")

        End If
    Loop Until startingPoint < 0
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @equisde See edit...The problem is though that once the tag has been enter once its stuck at repeatedly creating tags with every key stroke enterd

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving you an idea surely you have to modify this, but I think this will give you a start.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Text = richTextBox1.Text.Trim();
            int LastltIndex = Text.LastIndexOf('<');
            int LastgtIndex = Text.LastIndexOf('>');

            if ((LastltIndex < LastgtIndex) & LastltIndex != -1)
            {
                string Tag = Text.Substring(LastltIndex, (LastgtIndex - LastltIndex) + 1);
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Trim() + "\n" + Tag;
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, richTextBox1.Text.Length);
            }
        }
```